# How to define typeclass instance for higher kinded types in Scala?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming

I'm implementing a typeclass of serializable types in Scala. It's easy for simple types

```
trait Serializer[T] {
  def toBytes(a: T): Array[Byte]
}

implicit object StringSerializer extends Serializer[String] {
    override def toBytes(x: String) = ...
}

// similar codes for other simple types
```

But I got stuck in defining an instance for higher kinded types like Option[T], List[T], etc. Naturally, List[T] is serializable only if T is serializable. But how to express the constraint in Scala? My unsuccessful try:

```
implicit object ListSerializer extends Serializer[List[_]] {
  // won't compile
  override def toBytes[T: Serializer](a: List[T]): Array[Byte] = ...
}
```

Comment: How do you write *any*  generic function that accepts an object and serialises it?

Answer (score 8):

The thing is, you are using a existencial in `Serializer[List[_]]` effectively the only thing that an overriding method can accept then is `List[_]`. The way is to somehow provide a concrete type `List[T]` to the serializer. The trick:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)
// trait Serializer and the implicit object removed for brevity, the former was implemented with x.getBytes

implicit def listIsSerializable[T:Serializer]:Serializer[List[T]] = 
  new Serializer[List[T]] {
    def toBytes(xs:List[T])=xs.map(implicitly[Serializer[T]].toBytes).toArray.flatten   
  }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait Serializer
defined object StringSerializer
listIsSerializable: [T](implicit evidence$1: Serializer[T])Serializer[List[T]]

scala> implicitly[Serializer[List[String]]].toBytes(List("A","B"))
res0: Array[Byte] = Array(65, 66)
```