# Two parameter functions in type class instances of higher kinded types in Scala, how to translate this simple Haskell code to Scala?

Tags: scala, haskell, typeclass, implicit

The following Haskell code:

```hs
main = putStrLn $ "bla " ++ (toStr (A 1) (A 2))
--main2 = putStrLn $ "bla " ++ (toStr (A 1) (A "String")) -- does not compile, as it should
main3 = putStrLn $ "bla " ++ (toStr (A "String") (A "String"))

data A a = A a deriving Show -- (1) data type declaration 

class C a where -- (2) type class declaration
   toStr :: a-> a->String

instance C (A a) where -- (3) instance declaration
   toStr (A x) (A y) = "AA"
```

corresponds (roughly) to the following Scala code:

```
case class A[B](b:B) // (1) data type declaration

trait C[A] { // (2) type class declaration
  def toStr: A =>A=> String
  // this would correspond to "instance C (A a) where"
}


object Instance { 
  implicit object Instance extends C[A[_]] { // (3) instance declaration
    override def toStr: A[_] =>A[_] => String = x => x=> "AA"
//    override def toStr[T]: A[T] =>A[T] => String = x => x=> "AA" // this does not override anything, does not compile
  }
}

object Main{
  println(Instance.Instance.toStr(A(1))(A(2)))
  println(Instance.Instance.toStr(A(1))(A("bla"))) // this compiles, but it should not
}
```

How can I define `override def toStr: A[_] =>A[_] => String = x => x=> "AA"` such that `println(Instance.Instance.toStr(A(1))(A("bla")))` does not compile ?

As it (`putStrLn $ "bla " ++ (toStr (A 1) (A "String"))`) does not compile in the Haskell code ?

My attempt was `override def toStr[T]: A[T] =>A[T] => String = x => x=> "bla"` but that does not compile because that does not override `def toStr: A =>A=> String`
 in `C`.

In summary, how can I translate the above Haskell code to Scala ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to make instances as `object`s is not the right approach. It almost always is better to just make anonymous `def`s that implement the typeclass.

```
object Instance { 
  // Corresponds to `instance C (A a)`
  implicit def instance[T]: C[A[T]] = new C[A[T]] {
    override def toStr: A[T] => A[T] => String = x => y => "AA"
  }
}

object Main{
  println(Instance.instance.toStr(A(1))(A(2)))
  println(Instance.instance.toStr(A(1))(A("bla"))) // doesn't compile
}
```

So what was wrong with your approach? The root of the problem is that the wildcards `_` do not need to be equal - they can individually match different types (recall that `_` is just sugar for `x forSome { type x }`). To get around that, we need to introduce a generic parameter (which is quantified over the *whole* instance). The natural place to put that is on the `object`, but this is the second problem: objects don't accept generic parameters.

#### Why use `implicit def`

`implicit def` (with no arguments) is perfect for making type class instances. You can:

- introduce type variables as generic parameters on the method (as I did above with `B`)
- introduce superclass constraints as bounds on those generics. For example,

  ```
  // Corresponds to `instance C a => C (A a)`
  implicit def instance[T: C]: C[A[T]] = new C[A[T]] {
    override def toStr: A[T] => A[T] => String = x => y => (x,y) match {
      case (A(bx),A(by)) => "[" + implicitly[C[T]].toStr(bx)(by) + "]"
    }
  }

  // Corresponds to `instance C String`
  implicit val strInstance: C[String] = new C[String] {
    override def toStr: String => String => String = x => y => x + y
  }
  ```

  And with that, `implicitly[C[A[A[String]]]].toStr(A(A("hi")))(A(A("world")))` returns `[[hiworld]]`.

Comment: Nice, thanks, is this approach widely known ? Somehow I have not seen it yet.

Comment: @jhegedus I think this is a standard approach. I can't recall having seen it documented anywhere, but I'm certain it is. There is only one nasty gotcha with regards to superclasses - in some cases, Scala gives up trying to satisfy the superclass because it thinks it might be looping (check out `Lazy` in Shapeless).

Comment: @jhegedus Actually, Shapeless is a great place to read more about this sort of thing!

Comment: Yeah, I really should start to read about Shapeless before going to sleep in the evenings.

Comment: An answer I gave the other day that might help you understand what you were doing wrong, @jhegedus: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108537/how-to-define-typeclass-instance-for-higher-kinded-types-in-scala/

Comment: @pedrofurla as far as I can see your answer is also about using implicit defs instead of implicit objects, right ?

Comment: @jhegedus, that's accidental. It's about existentials vs universal quantifiers.